# Quick tumblr boo-lean + Getting text function

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

James here. Quick, and simple question for you guys. I'm working with a tumblr theme which uses a text option, which means the user can type whatever they want, and it'll display on the blog. The text options however do not work with javascript, so I can't use the text option for amount of columns and the text option for spacing between posts in my script that organizes the whole page. I know there is a way, but I don't know how to do this, to just create an invisible div with the boo lean text in it, and then use jQuery to get the text inside the div to use as a variable? I was thinking like .text(); or .html(); but I have no clue. Any codes or help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new at this jquery thing, so it'd mean a lot.

EDIT: If this is confusing for anyone, I basically need to use jQuery to get text inside an invisible element and use that text as a variable.

Comment: This word "boolean" -- I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: Oh, I just looked up the meaning. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'boolean' here, but per your edit you want:

```
$('#id-of-element').text()
```

if you only want the text in the div or,

```
$('#id-of-element').html()
```

if you want the HTML. So if the div contains:

```
<h1>foo</h1>,
```

`text()` will give you "foo", while `html()` will give you "`<h1>foo</h1>`".

Comment: The whole code is messed up now... The whole point of this was so the user could pick the amount of columns they want and how much spacing they want between the columns.

Comment: Which script are we looking at?

Comment: The one all the way at the bottom of the page.

Comment: The page basically just killed itself... What's wrong with the code? D: